# Find local maximum or minimum in 2 variable function

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, optimization, partial-derivative

So, I encountered a question (don't worry it's not H.W.) where I have a function with two variables, and I need to find local maximum / minimum points if exists.

(More precisely, it is a utility function and I'd like to maximize s1 value)

Here's the function (b is some constant in (0, 1/4]):

$$u_1(s_1,s_2)=\frac 12[4(s_1+s_2+bs_1s_2)]-s_1^2$$

Now, finding s1 is easy - first derivative equals 0: $s1 = 1 + b * s2$.

It is the first time I encounter such question, where I have to check maximum / minimum of a point in a function with two variables instead of one variable, so I went to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test) to learn more about how to approach it.

I see that I have to calculate the determinant of the Hessian matrix, noted as D in wiki.

So, I calculated:

$$D(x,y)=\det(H(x,y))=f_{xx}(x,y)f_{yy}(x,y)-\left(f_{xy}(x,y)\right)^2$$

The result is: $-2 * 0 - (2b)^2$

(Since I have no variables in the second derivatives, the result is constant numbers and I don't have to assign the actual point).

Now, negative D means saddle point. But, the result of the exercise says it is a maximum one.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which is your domain? If it is $\mathbb{R}^2$, clearly there aren't max and min.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that avoids using the Hessian.

The function is always concave (parabolic) in $s_1$. Holding fixed $s_2$ the function is a reaches it's maximum value at $s_1=1+bs_2$. Since the function is concave in $s_1$ it has no local minimum.

Does it have a local maximum? If so, it must occur where $s_1=1+bs_2$. Plugging in this to the objective yields a function that is convex and parabolic in $s_2$. Because it is convex in $s_2$ it cannot have a local maximum.

Since the function cannot have a local maximum or minimum, any stationary point must be a saddle.

Comment: Well, it appeared in an exam last year and the answer was that it is a local maximum...